# Write environmental specific web.xml, log4j.xml with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have something like this in my web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>${path}/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And inside the log4j.xml:

```
<appender name="errorfile" 
    class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${logfiles}/errors.log" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR" />
    <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%t] (%c) - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

When gradle builds I want to inject correct values ${path} and ${logfiles} by providing them in the gradle.properties file.

Ideally, I would like to run a task that preps the files independently from building. This way the build process might be easier.

Comment: Right now I doing a copy and replace flow suggested by @madhead below. I just wanted to know what the proper approach was for this scenario. I couldn't find directly relevant information in the docs, but I thought it would be common scenario when deploying to different environments.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle's [`Copy`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) task supports filtering, i.e. replacing placeholders (`${property}`) with values from arbitrary property sources. In your case it will be something like:

```
processResources {
    expand project.properties
}
```

It will replace all tokens for files in `src/main/resources` during `processResources` task with values from `project.properties` (and `gradle.properties` populate them).